# Calculating the pearson coefficients in a keras model met with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I'm using pearson correlation coefficients as the input features of the MLP model, and meeting with problem when establishing the model.

I've updated and run my code according to **today**'s favorable comment that wrapping the function inside a Lambda layer, whereas the same error still occurs. I thought I've fixed the errors **today** mentioned. Below is my updated code:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Input, Lambda, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, Add, Flatten, Dense, Concatenate
from keras.models import Model, Sequential
import keras.backend as K

def cal_cor(x):
    a, b = x
    assert a.shape[1] == b.shape[1], 'lengths not compatible'

    a_mean = K.mean(a)
    b_mean = K.mean(b)
    a_norm = a - a_mean
    b_norm = b - b_mean
    numerator = a_norm * b_norm

    a_var = K.square(a_norm)
    b_var = K.square(b_norm)
    denominator = (a_var * b_var) ** 0.5

    return numerator / denominator

def cnn_with_pearson():

    # Pearson part
    cor_layer = Lambda(function=cal_cor, name='correlation_layer')

    cors = []
    for i in range(28):
        cor_added = []
        for j in range(28):
            if i == j:
                continue
            cor_added.append( cor_layer( [input[:, i, :, 0], input[:, j, :, 0]] ) )
        cors.append(Add()(cor_added))

    con = Concatenate()(cors)
    f = Flatten()(K.expand_dims(con, -1))
    d = Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')(f)
    model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=d)

    return model

model = cnn_with_pearson()
```

Error occurs in the line `model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=d)`:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap your function inside a [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer to let Keras be able to track it and augment its returned tensor(s) with necessary information. To do this, you need to modify the definition of your function as well, since it must take a list of tensors as input:

```
def cal_cor(x):
    a, b = x

    # the rest is the same ...
```

Then define the Lambda layer for that:

```
cor_layer = Lambda(cal_cor)
```

and then use it like this:

```
cor_added = []
for j in range(28):
    if i == j:
        continue
    cor_added.append(cor_layer(input[:, i, :, 0], input[:, j, :, 0]))

cors.append(Add()(cor_added))
```

Note that for addition, we also need to use the [`Add`](https://keras.io/layers/merge/#add) layer (`from keras.layers import Add`).